# Web site link change using HTAaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to use .htaccess to rewrite a sub domain?

Example:

`http://fashion.example.com`
shows the content of

`http://example.com/index.php?name=fashion`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine  on

RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*).example.com/$ index.php?name=$1

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess Rules in your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 added

Comment: What folder is your subdomain `fashion.example.com` currently pointing to?

Comment: No folder as sub domain using get parameter as subdomain

Comment: Then first you need to create DNS record for your `fashion` sub domain and point it to your root

Comment: Are both domains on same host pointing to same `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: @anubhava Yes   *

Comment: What is URL is `http://fashion.example.com/someFile.php` ?

Comment: @anubhava http://example.com/index.php?name=fashion

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your subdomain is pointing to the same directory as your main domain, you can use something like  the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$  /index.php?name=%1 [L]
```

Comment: fashion name is udpate not static

Comment: oops.. I really  missed it.

Comment: @BhavikGajjar, kindly do provide more information what is not working? eg--> which url failed?, what error you got in your browser? And what error you seen in your logs. Kindly do mention these details so that we could help more on this one, thanks.

Comment: https://domain_name.in/index.html?name=logi

needs to be like https://logi.domain_name.in

Comment: error be like

This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in logi.logieagle.in.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: @AmitVerma Logi is not static value it's a query string param

Comment: @BhavikGajjar You need to create subDomain on your DNS zone first. URL rewriting can not do this.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?name=%1 [L,QSA]
``
```